# Bundle install --deployment not working with "gcc: Permission denied"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I've been setting up my server to run a Rails application on it, and recently started configuring Capistrano for deployment.  The deployment itself seems to be fairly in line, but it fails when it tries to run `bundle install --deployment`.  Excerpt from the logs:

```
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 creating Makefile
 make
 compiling crypt_blowfish.c
 make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
 make: *** [crypt_blowfish.o] Error 127
 Gem files will remain installed in /home/.../public_html/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
 Results logged to /home/.../public_html/v4/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
 An error occurred while installing bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1), and Bundler cannot
 continue.
 Make sure that `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

For what it's worth, `gem install bcrypt-ruby -v '3.0.1'` fails as the non-root user (even with sudo privileges).  It DOES work as the root user.

The gem_make.out log says:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
make: execvp: gcc: Permission denied
make: *** [crypt_blowfish.o] Error 127
```

Permission denied.  Which is interesting because I thought that was the point of using `bundle install --deployment`.  I've looked everywhere and not found anything that helps.

I had a feeling that it might have to do with the fact that ruby is installed presumably as the root user.  That is -- it was already installed when I got to the server.  I tried to reinstall ruby using RVM (as the non-root user, though either way I got the same result) and got:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Installing requirements for centos, might require sudo password.
Installing required packages: gcc-c++, libyaml-devel, libffi-devel...................................................................................
Error running 'requirements_centos_libs_install gcc-c++ libyaml-devel libffi-devel',
please read /home/.../.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/1376056268_package_install_gcc-c++_libyaml-devel_libffi-devel.log
```

And the log there says...

```
Transaction Check Error:
  package libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 is already installed
  package gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.x86_64 is already installed
  package mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-3.el6_4.x86_64 is already installed
  package libstdc++-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  package libffi-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 is already installed
  file /sbin/ldconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686
  file /sbin/sln from install of glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686
  file /usr/sbin/iconvconfig from install of glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686
```

Long story short I'm sort of at a loss for what to do.

Running CentOS 6.4 / cPanel.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: have you tried `sudo bundle install --deployment` ?

Comment: Tried that but no luck.

    `sudo -i bundle install
    ERROR: RVM Ruby not used, run `rvm use 2.0.0` first.`

`    sudo bundle install
    sudo: bundle: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

It turns out that a few things were the issue here:

1. You can't install RVM on a cPanel server
2. You also can't install gems without the `sudo` command if you're not the root user (on a cPanel server).

I ended up installing ruby as the user in question here (following [this guide](http://paul-wong-jr.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-and-compiling-ruby-from.html)) and more or less got what I wanted.

I needed to do `sudo bundle install --deployment` to really get it working, but that aside that's what worked for me.

Thanks for all your help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just reinstalling it have you tried completely removing ruby and reinstalling it with rvm?

Comment: Thanks! I have tried that but I still get the `package glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.x86_64 is already installed` etc. etc. error then.

Comment: Try removing glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.2.i686 and redoing the process.

Comment: Gave that a go -- `Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected` which completely kills the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fix `rvm` permissions with:

```
rvmsudo rvm cleanup all
```

In theory, `sudo` should be never required while using `rvm`.