# Ruby Gems : sudo gems not showing with gems

Tags: gcc, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, sudo, sudoers

I have a sudo rights on my ssh user. I can not run `sudo bundle install` command but can run `bundle install` without sudo.
Once I run the `bundle install`, Few gems get install but those who need `gcc` and `c++` compiler I have to install in sudo permissions like `sudo gem install json -v '1.8.0'`.

Now if I try to run bundle that gem is not available due to installed with sudo permission.

Is there any other way to install such compiler gems without sudo?

Comment: may I know did you use `rvm`?

Comment: `yes`. I have used rvm and all others gems are installed with rvm

Comment: may I know which Os are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148359/bundle-install-deployment-not-working-with-gcc-permission-denied Please follow it

Comment: I have replied my own answer for `cpanel` `rvm` worked with `rvmsudo rvm install ruby 1.9.3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not getting the right environement for installing ruby and gemsets . But 
`rvmsudo` worked for me

I tried installing those gems which required compiler like

`rvmsudo gem install json -v  '1.8.0'`

And it worked for me.

I am having only local user access which does not have any rights to run commands like `yum`